# SED - Insert saved value after certain pattern when a specific string doesn't exist in the file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have **files that look similar to this**:

```
LET: DimX   (2660.0)
LET: DimZ   (1050.0)
LET: DimS   (0.8)
LET: DREHEN (20)

DIM: X DimX
     Z DimZ+0.5
     S DimS
     

REF: X1 FOD-23.24
     X2 FOD-23.24
     Z1 FOD-24.86
     Z2 FOD-24.86

POS: CENT_FUNC 1
     QSU 10 QSD 10
     TURN_AROUND
```

And like this - **note the STAINLESS** in the 2nd one:

```
LET: DimX   (2660.0)
LET: DimZ   (1050.0)
LET: DimS   (0.7)
LET: DREHEN (20)

DIM: X DimX
     Z DimZ+0.5
     S DimS
     STAINLESS

REF: X1 FOD-23.24
     X2 FOD-23.24
     Z1 FOD-24.86
     Z2 FOD-24.86

POS: CENT_FUNC 1
     QSU 10 QSD 10
     TURN_AROUND
```

I want to save the value in Brackets in the line matching
*LET: DimS   (**XX**)*
and insert a new line
*MAT: 'XX correction*' - where XX is the save value.
after *S DimS*

- But only if the file whole doesn't contain the string STAINLESS.

So this should be the **outcome** for the **1st example**:

```
LET: DimX   (2660.0)
LET: DimZ   (1050.0)
LET: DimS   (0.8)
LET: DREHEN (20)

DIM: X DimX
     Z DimZ+0.5
     S DimS
     MAT: '0.8 correction'


REF: X1 FOD-23.24
     X2 FOD-23.24
     Z1 FOD-24.86
     Z2 FOD-24.86

POS: CENT_FUNC 1
     QSU 10 QSD 10
     TURN_AROUND
```

**Outcome** of the **2nd example** should stay as it was as it contains STAINLESS:

```
LET: DimX   (2660.0)
LET: DimZ   (1050.0)
LET: DimS   (0.7)
LET: DREHEN (20)

DIM: X DimX
     Z DimZ+0.5
     S DimS
     STAINLESS

REF: X1 FOD-23.24
     X2 FOD-23.24
     Z1 FOD-24.86
     Z2 FOD-24.86

POS: CENT_FUNC 1
     QSU 10 QSD 10
     TURN_AROUND
```

**I've tried this** to add the line after S DimS pattern:

```
sed -i -E '/S DimS/I a  \\t MAT: "'"0.8 correction"'"'
```

But that just gives me:

```
LET: DimX   (2660.0)
LET: DimZ   (1050.0)
LET: DimS   (0.8)
LET: DREHEN (20)

DIM: X DimX
     Z DimZ+0.5
     S DimS
     MAT: "0.8 correction"

REF: X1 FOD-23.24
     X2 FOD-23.24
     Z1 FOD-24.86
     Z2 FOD-24.86

POS: CENT_FUNC 1
     QSU 10 QSD 10
     TURN_AROUND
```

And:

```
    LET: DimX   (2660.0)
LET: DimZ   (1050.0)
LET: DimS   (0.7)
LET: DREHEN (20)

DIM: X DimX
     Z DimZ+0.5
     S DimS
     MAT: "0.8 correction"
     STAINLESS

REF: X1 FOD-23.24
     X2 FOD-23.24
     Z1 FOD-24.86
     Z2 FOD-24.86

POS: CENT_FUNC 1
     QSU 10 QSD 10
     TURN_AROUND
```

And obvioulsy won't save the value in the brackets...

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're amenable to an awk solution, which is often easier than sed when there's logic to perform beyond simple string manipulation ...

```
# Capture the correction amount
/LET: DimS/ { correction = $3; gsub(/[()]/, "", correction) }

# Get ready to print
$1 == "DIM:" { f = 1 }

# Abort print!!
$1 == "STAINLESS" { f = 0 }

# Now is the time to print the extra line if the flag is still set
NF == 0 && f { printf "     MAT: '%s correction'\n", correction; f = 0 }

# Output the original lines of the file
{ print }
```

Test first example:

```
$ awk -f a.awk file
LET: DimX   (2660.0)
LET: DimZ   (1050.0)
LET: DimS   (0.8)
LET: DREHEN (20)

DIM: X DimX
     Z DimZ+0.5
     S DimS
     MAT: '0.8 correction'


REF: X1 FOD-23.24
     X2 FOD-23.24
     Z1 FOD-24.86
     Z2 FOD-24.86

POS: CENT_FUNC 1
     QSU 10 QSD 10
     TURN_AROUND
```

Try it with your second "STAINLESS" example and you'll see that the extra line is not printed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;/STAINLESS/b;
    s/^(.*LET:\sDimS\s*\(([^)]*).*\n(\s*)S DimS[^\n]*\n)/\1\3MAT: '\''\2 correction'\''/' file
```

Gather up the entire file into memory and test it to see if it contains the word `STAINLESS`. If so, bail out otherwise: using pattern matching insert the required text.